# Can you add a pause to a Better Touch Tool macro?

Tags: macos, bettertouchtool

I was hoping that there could be some way to have the first action go, then wait .1 seconds before the next action. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can set it by "Delay Next Action" in Trigger Predefined Action.